# How to migrate framework to Swift 5.2

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

Carthage needs me to upgrade my framework to Swift 5.2, because it is still at Swift 5.1.3 My problem is that I don't see Swift 5.2 in build settings under `Swift Language Version`. What would be the procedure to migrate the framework to Swift 5.2 and build it with Swift 5.2?

Comment: if you have the source code for the framework, build it. if not you have to have the owner do it for you. If that can't be done, you can't use the framework anymore.

Comment: Basically the answer depends on what "my" means.

Comment: By my I mean mine. Ok, so the build itself seems to be sufficient. Thanks